# MVVM and clean architecture both are same in flutter?

Tags: flutter, clean-architecture

i am beginner in flutter now and i want to learn software architecture patterns but many confusion in this. i want to know clean architecture and MVVM both are same?
if no?what is difference between them and what is MVVM + clean architecture in flutter
and please let me know best resource to learn as beginner

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-mvvm-in-flutter-4b28b63da2ca Read the complete Documentation

Comment: is paid to access?

Comment: open in incognito mode

Comment: MVVM seems like a bad match for an already-reactive framework like Flutter, and more designed when you have to work out the reactive components yourself.  But we already have setState and InheritedWidget to manage our builds dependent on local and nearby state, so we really don't need a "viewmodel".  Thus, I prefer just thinking of MVC and designing according to that.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with @RandalSchwartz's opinion. MVVM is indeed a very good match for Flutter as a (pseudo-)declarative framework. It's a design pattern that is typically used for cases where a declarative paradigm is used and is also recommended e.g. for Swift UI. I would argue in favor of MVVM in Flutter when using a clean architecture and even advice against using MVC. MVC is in my opinion better suited when working with imperative paradigms, like the old Swift (prior to Swift UI).

Comment: And to answer the initial question: I think that the View and ViewModel are part of the presentation layer, while the model comprises the domain and data layer. In essence, MVVM and Clean architecture can be used in tandem, but they focus on different parts of your app. For example, MVVM describes more in detail how to implement the presentation layer (and to my understanding, does not give very concrete guidelines on how to implement the parts of the model in detail), while clean architecture focuses on other aspects of the architecture, which would go beyond the character limits of this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first read Uncle Bob's explanation of [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

Clean Architecture separates the development (the app in your case) into different layers (most commons are Presentation, Domain, and Data).

For your question: MVVM is actually part of the Presentation layer, in Flutter it's quite similar to the [BLoC pattern](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/basics/what-is-the-bloc-pattern/2021/2084/).

Answer (score 0):

Clean architecture separates the application into different layers like data, domain, application
MVVM separate view model and the view for the screen in the application folder

Answer (score 0):

**MVVM** is a pattern that is used on the **Presentation Layer** of the **Clean Architecture**.
BLoC is a more popular alternative to MVVM in the Flutter world.

In [this article](https://medium.com/itnext/flutter-modularized-dependency-injection-4362649f84ed), I gave an example of an architecture adhering to the Clean Architecture Principles. It depicts how to use physical layer separation instead of just using folder separation. Also, it uses BLoC as a state management on the presentation layer. You can [check out this repo](https://github.com/Pavel-Sulimau/flutter_modularized_di) to play with the example and see how the dependencies are organized there.

So, on the diagram below the BLoC will be encapsulated/hidden inside the **presentation** layer of the Clean Architectured solution.

Hope that helps!

[image]